# set applicationTags property in YARN for jobs submitted by CLI

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'd like to track some related applications in YARN. They're submitted via command line, e.g.

```
yarn jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar pi 10 100
```

Python has a really [easy-to-use YARN client](http://python-client-for-hadoop-yarn-api.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) that returns the following:

```
finalStatus = SUCCEEDED
id = application_1458083392566_0929
state = FINISHED
name = QuasiMonteCarlo
applicationType = MAPREDUCE
user = awoolford
applicationTags = 
[...etc...]
```

I notice there's an `applicationTags` property. This would be an ideal way to track groups of related applications. I tried setting it via `HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS`, e.g.

```
HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-DapplicationTags=batch123,chunk62" hadoop jar [...etc...]
```

... but the `applicationTags` string didn't show up in YARN when I tried to retrieve them via the Python client.

Q) How can I submit a YARN job and populate the `applicationTags` property from the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The property that needs to be set is called `mapreduce.job.tags` (see [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-5699)). So, for the calculate Pi MapReduce example, you'd tag the job like this:

```
yarn jar hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar pi -Dmapreduce.job.tags=myJobTag 10 100
```

Credit to [Neerja Khattar](https://www.linkedin.com/in/neerja-khattar-59a68713) from Cloudera for figuring out how to do this.